# Using AutoMapper to load entities from the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, automapper

Most of what I've read (e.g. [from the author](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/)) indicates that AutoMapper should be used to map an an entity to a DTO. It should not load anything from the database.

But what if I have this:

```
public class Customer {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDto {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<int> OrderIds { get; set; }   // here is the problem
}
```

I need to map *from DTO to entity* (i.e. from `CustomerDto` to `Customer`), but first I must use that list of foreign keys to load corresponding entities from the database. AutoMapper can do that with a [custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591288/3959480).

I agree that it doesn't feel right... but what are the alternatives? Sticking that logic into a controller, service, a repository, some manager class? All that seems to be pushing the logic somewhere else, in the same tier. And if I do that, I must also perform the mapping manually!

From a DDD perspective, the DTO should not be part of the domain. So AutoMapper is also not part of the domain, because it knows about that DTO. So AutoMapper is in the same tier as the controllers, services, etc.

*So does it make sense to put the DTO-to-entity logic (which includes accessing the database, and possibly throwing exceptions) into an AutoMapper mapping?*

**EDIT**
@ChrisSimon's great answer below explains from a DDD perspective why I shouldn't do this. From a non-DDD perspective, is there a compelling reason not to use AutoMapper to load from the db?

Comment: PS this is not a subjective question. I'd like to know what people do in this case - I'd like to know my options. Even the author believes his tool shouldn't be used to do anything but basic object-to-object mapping.

Comment: Do you mean DTO - entity mapping or the other way around?

Comment: @tomliversidge DTO-to-entity (but where the entity must have its navigation properties loaded from the db based on FKs in the DTO)

Comment: What is the business process here? Why do you need to load the full order objects?

Comment: @tomliversidge Client app POSTs a new `CustomerDto` to server, for insertion into the db as a new `Customer` entity. But that DTO contains FKs to navigation properties (`Order`), so they must be loaded (and perform validation that they exist, etc.) before I can insert the parent entity.

Comment: Won't the orders just end up as foreign keys when saved in the database though? (Presuming relational db here) What's the point in loading a full set of objects just to then save only the foreign key references?

Comment: @tomliversidge No refer to the two classes above... the DTO used by the client has a list of FKs (as it can't handle 1:n relationships), but on the server the list is of child entities.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I'm trying to understand why you need the entities loading. 'Perform validation that they exist, etc.' is all you've explained. I was thinking that maybe the answer to your question is that they don't need loading at all, but maybe there is a business process that needs them loaded

Comment: @tomliversidge Ah okay, there is not biz reason to load them. I need to insert a new `Customer` entity. I might need to add related child entities (`Order`s or `Location` or `CustomerType` or whatever) to that new entity. So my assumption is I must load them and do a `entity.Order.Add(child)`. I can't use `.Attach()` because I get an FK from the client which may not exist. Hence I wanted to lean on AutoMapper to do this for me, because it can map the rest of the DTO to entity, just not the child properties. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Validation = business rules. I don't know what .Attach() is - some ORM thing?! My point was simply you could do a repository.Save(customerDTO) without needing to load the Order entities if there are no invariants to enforce

Answer (score 6):

To start with, I'm going to summarise my understanding of Entities in DDD:

1. Entities can be created - often using a factory.  This is the start of their life-cycle.
2. Entities can be mutated - have their state modified - by calling methods on the entity.  This is how they progress through their lifecycle.  By ensuring that the entity owns its own state, and can only have its state modified by calling its methods, the logic that controls the entity's state is all within the entity class, leading to cleaner separation of business logic and more maintainable systems.

Using Automapper to convert from a Dto to the entity means the entity is giving up ownership of its state. If the dto is in an invalid state and you map that directly onto the entity, the entity may end up in an invalid state - you have lost the value of making entities contain data + logic, which is the foundation of the DDD entity.

To make a suggestion as to how you should approach this, I'd ask - what is the operation you are trying to achieve? DDD encourages us not to think about CRUD operations, but to think about real business processes, and to model them on our entities.  In this case it looks like you are linking Orders to the Customer entity.

In an Application Service I would have a method like:

```
void LinkOrdersToCustomer(CustomerDto dto)
{
    using (var dbTxn = _txnFactory.NewTransaction())
    {
        var customer = _customerRepository.Get(dto.Id);
        foreach (var orderId in dto.OrderIds)
        {
            var order = _orderRepository.Get(orderId);
            customer.LinkToOrder(order);
        }
        dbTxn.Save();
    }
}
```

Within the LinkToOrder method, I would have explicit logic that did things like:

- Check that order is not null
- Check that the customer's state permits adding the order (are they currently active? is their account closed? etc.)
- Check that the order actually does belong to the customer (what would happen if the order referenced by orderId belonged to another customer?)
- Ask the order (via a method on the order entity) if it is in a valid state to be added to a customer.

Only then would I add it to the Customers Order's collection.

This way, the application 'flow' and infrastructure management is contained within the application/services layer, but the true business logic is contained within the domain layer - within your entities.

If the above requirements are not relevant in your application, you may have other requirements. If not, then perhaps it is not necessary to go the route of DDD - while DDD has a lot to add, its overheads are generally only worth it in systems with lots of complex business logic.

This isn't related to the question you asked, but I'd also suggest you take a look at the modelling of Customer and Order.  Are they both independent [Aggregates](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html)?  If so, modelling Customer as containing a collection of Order may lead to problems down the road - what happens when a customer has a million orders?  Even if the collection is lazy loaded, you know at some point something will attempt to load it, and there goes your performance.  There's some great reading about aggregate design here: http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/ which recommends modelling references by Id rather than reference.  In your case, you could have a collection of OrderIds, or possibly even a completely new entity to represent the link - `CustomerOrderLink` which would have two properties - CustomerId, and OrderId.  Then none of your entities would have embedded collections.

Comment: Thanks for your considered and lengthy response. And from a pure DDD perspective, you are of course correct. I want to wait for some more answers though as well (which are not strictly DDD)...

Comment: In the first part of your explanation, you said the entity can be materialised from the db by a factory (or DbContext). So why not by AutoMapper? I appreicate what you're saying, but practically, how is using AutoMapper any different? I would assume that from a DDD perspective, it is in the same layer as the factories, services, etc.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a factory doesn't materialise the entity - it creates it - at the start of its lifecycle.  A DbContext can materialise it from the database (and in doing so is playing the role of the repository in the traditional DDD sense).  The difference is that the contract of the repository is to store and retrieve the entity state without modifying it.  As the persistence is within the control of your application, you know that while the entity state is persisted, it's not being modified.  However, a Dto, entering your application from the outside world, is in an uncontrolled state.

Comment: We have a DDD ninja here! :-) The DTO came from outside world (client), I didn't create it, I don't know if it's valid, then, therefore, I can't use AutoMapper to convert it into a new entity? So alternative is to perform mapping by hand... but AutoMapper can do that for me. I understand your answer, but my confusion is that adding custom mapping code in some service is another layer of indirection, just to remain pure? Not being sarcastic, I'm trying to justify the extra code. I appreciate the DDD way (and try to remain pure), it just seems like overkill sometimes, like in this case. :)

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it, the more I realise I'm arguing about DDD with you, which is silly of me. From a DDD perspective, your answer is 100% correct. I need to decide whether to do this the DDD way, or not. DDD sure is heavy though!! :-)

Comment: Yep - if you're getting no value from the explicit method, you might not need DDD - it's not for all applications.  What you see as just a 'custom mapping', a DDD system sees as business process and passes the request through business logic in the entity, to ensure the business rules are followed.  It's not just about 'purity' - if you have many rules, you have to keep them together (in the entity) or it gets out of control, scattered around different services.  If you don't have such business rules, I totally agree - pragmatism wins, and my recommendation is overkill.

Comment: Thanks for not getting upset by my comments. DDD discussions often get out of control. It's great in certain cases, but when it isn't, it and discussions of it become nasty... (at my workplace anyway lol)

Comment: Ha! No worries - I'm always all for just what works.  Where DDD is needed, it's a lifesaver, but where it isn't it's a waste of time and energy.  I only addressed your question in the context of DDD because you tagged it, and referenced it in your question.  But I'd still encourage you to ponder if including a collection of Orders in your Customer is how you want to do this... it smells to me like a lurking performance issue waiting to bite you down the road.  But that's just a guess - without more knowledge of your system and context, I could be completely wrong.